# Whats the difference of using a context like these two approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Whats the difference of using a context like these two approach

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    MyContext db = new MyContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.First(m => m.Id == 1));
    }
    // ...
}
```

or

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
        {
            return View(db.Users.First(m => m.Id == 1));
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, here's how you dispose of the db context when created at the controller level:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    MyContext db = new MyContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.First(m => m.Id == 1));
    }
    // ...

    // This is automatically called by the framework, after
    // the ActionResult.ExecuteResult() is called.
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && db != null)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

The controller's Dispose method is called after the view is executed. This would allow you to call any deferred properties in your view (IQueryables, lazy-loaded properties). Disposing of the dbcontext within the action wouldn't allow that (second example). In the second example, any references to deferred actions would give you an exception.

Comment: Woops, that would be a copy/paste error. Should have been 'db' - fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

In the first, the context is available class-wide. It is also never properly disposed of after its initial use (at least not in the context of the code that you've given us).

In the second, the context is instantiated inside of a `using` block. After the block, the context is properly disposed of.

Comment: Whats the properly way to dispose it? And once properly diposed, is there any difference between both approach?

Comment: @Fabrico - the proper way to dispose of a context is a) use a using() statement or b) call db.Dispose() when you are done with it.  Be aware, that if you are lazy loading items from your view (IE, calling child properties or are not calling .ToList() on a collection), you will get a runtime error as the context will be disposed and no longer available.

Comment: Can i `db.Dispose()` inside `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
   base.Dispose(disposing);
  }` of my controller?